# Is it a good idea to inject a TestSettings parameter to a method to make it (Unit or integration) Testable?

Tags: oop, unit-testing, design-patterns, tdd, integration-testing

Is it a good practice to introduce a TestSettings class in order to provide flexible testing possibilities of a method that has many processes inside?

Maybe not a good example but can be simple: Suppose that I have this method and I want to test its sub-processes:

```
public void TheBigMethod(myMethodParameters parameter)
{

  if(parameter.Condition1)
   {
     MethodForCondition1("BigMac"); 
   }

  if(parameter.Condition2)
   {
     MethodForCondition2("MilkShake"); 
   }

  if(parameter.Condition3)
   {
     MethodForCondition3("Coke"); 
   }

  SomeCommonMethod1('A');
  SomeCommonMethod2('B');
  SomeCommonMethod3('C');
}
```

And imagine that I have unit tests for all

- void MethodForCondition1 (string s)
- void MethodForCondition2 (string s)
- void MethodForCondition3 (string s)
- void SomeCommonMethod1 (char c)
- void SomeCommonMethod2 (char c)
- void SomeCommonMethod3 (char c)

And now i want to test the TheBigMethod itself by introducing such test methods with required Asserts in them:

- TheBigMethod_MethodForCondition1_TestCaseX_DoesGood
- TheBigMethod_MethodForCondition2_TestCaseY_DoesGood
- TheBigMethod_MethodForCondition3_TestCaseZ_DoesGood
- TheBigMethod_SomeCommonMethod1_TestCaseU_DoesGood
- TheBigMethod_SomeCommonMethod2_TestCaseP_DoesGood
- TheBigMethod_SomeCommonMethod3_TestCaseQ_DoesGood

So, I want TheBigMethod to be **exit-able** at some points if it is called by one of my integration tests above.

```
public void TheBigMethod(myMethodParameters parameter, TestSettings setting)
{

  if(parameter.Condition1)
   {
     MethodForCondition1("BigMac"); 

     if(setting.ExitAfter_MethodForCondition1)
        return;

   }

  if(parameter.Condition2)
   {
     MethodForCondition2("MilkShake"); 

     if(setting.ExitAfter_MethodForCondition2)
        return;

   }

  if(parameter.Condition3)
   {
     MethodForCondition3("Coke"); 

     if(setting.ExitAfter_MethodForCondition3)
        return;

   }

  SomeCommonMethod1('A');
  if(setting.ExitAfter_SomeCommonMethod1)
       return;

  SomeCommonMethod2('B');
  if(setting.ExitAfter_SomeCommonMethod2)
       return;

  SomeCommonMethod3('C');
  if(setting.ExitAfter_SomeCommonMethod3)
       return;
}
```

Even though it looks it does what I need to introduce a TestSetting parameter can makee the code less readable and does not look nice to have testing logic and the main functionality combined to me.

Can you advise a better design for such cases so that it can replace a TestSetting parameter idea?

thanks

Comment: In TDD, you write tests in order to help and achieve the correct design (that is, test first). You seem to be writing tests after you already have a design - this is **not** TDD.

Comment: Why do you need to exit the method earlier?

Comment: @Oded: Correct. Thanks for highlighting it. Actually I came up with this question when I was given a legacy code that has no tests. Anyway, do you have an opinion or advise on my question? I would appreciate.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger: Because if it passes, I dont want to test the rest of the processes -talking on this example. Let's say, if the BIG method has to complete steps A,B,C,D,E,F. I want to test the steps in the BIG method first only A. Then in another test from A to B. And then A,B,C. And then A,B,C,D. Until I get GREEN light for A to F.

Comment: Adding a TestSettings parameter would really be my very last resort. Can't you stub the method calls you don't need? I would even prefer  adding a parameter object that holds the methods to be called to adding a TestSettings parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would (IMO) be a very bad thing to add this TestSetting. An alternative would be to add an interface (or set of interfaces) for MethodForCondition*X* and SomeCommonMethod*X*. The test each of the MethodForCondition*X* & SomeCommonMethod*X* in isolation and pass in a stub for TheBigMethod which validates that MethodForCondition*X* is called with value Z.

**Edit**: You could also make the methods virtual if you don't want to use an interface.

Comment: So maybe for all the processes that will be accomplished, I can introduce a IBigMehtodManager interface that has public methods for all processes (MethodForCondition*X* and SomeCommonMethod*X*) and I can create stub in my tests that implements IBigMethodManager Basicaly I replacec BigMehtodManager class with a stub TestableBigMethodManager : IBigMethodManager.

Comment: so in the end the method signature will be like this----> public void TheBigMethod(myMethodParameters parameter, IBigMethodManager manager)

Comment: I would likely inject the "IBigMethodManager" into the class rather than just that method (unless TheBigMethod is static). But that is the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the game here, but I would concur that mixing test and production code is a big code smell to be avoided.  Big methods in legacy code provide all sorts of issues.  I would highly recommend reading Michael Feather's [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052).  It's all about dealing with the myriad of problems encountered in legacy code and how to deal with them.

Comment: Thanks for the pointing to this book. I have added to my list already.